# merge from another repo git

Tags: git, github

I cloned a project from git and I did some changes and I now I want to import the changes done on the original repo and keep my changes in the same time !
I added a new remote :

`git add remote original_repo`

`git fetch original_repo`

`git checkout -b branch_for_merge original_repo/master`

the problem is when I do :
`git status`

I can't find the changed files , it gives me :

```
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

what should I do to find changes and resolve conflicts and merge the branch  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `git checkout -b branch_for_merge original_repo/master`

This makes `branch_for_merge` point to the same commit as `original_repo/master` and makes no sense at all.

What you want to do is this (assuming you did your work on your local `master` branch):

```
git checkout master    # just to be sure
git pull original_repo master
```

This will fetch any changes from `original_repo` (no-op since you already did so yourself) and then do a `git merge original_repo/master` for you. The only benefit over `git fetch ; git merge original/repo_master` is a slightly more helpfull commit message (which you can edit of course).

Comment: I love saving lifes. By the way, the `git rebase` mentioned in the other answer is pretty nice too, you now get to read up on both approaches and decide for yourself. You have two life-savers now! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
`git fetch`
```

The above instruction will go to the remote repository and besically copy whatever is there and store it under whatever name you've given your remote repository on your local machine (ex. origin/...). Bare in mind, at this point your local repository is not merged with the local copy of the remote repository.

```
`git checkout <branch>`
```

The above instruction will change branch to whichever you specify in `<branch>`.

```
`git rebase <remote>/<branch>`
```

Now when you are on the selected `<branch>`, this instruction will take whatever is on `<branch>` and reply it on top of `<remote>/<branch>`.

Alternatively, you can run

```
`git merge <remote>/<branch>`
```

This will make a merge commit and bring your `<branch>` up-to-date with the `<remote>/<branch>`